# Python csv.reader when line is encapsulated by strings

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to read a csv file.

```
    with open(os.path.join(folder,mfile),'r') as csvfile:
        fileReads = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for i, line in enumerate(fileReads):
            print 'line[{}] = {}'.format(i, line)
```

Unfortunately, my data is contained in the following format in the CSV file:

```
"val1, val2, val3"
```

(including quotes, don't ask why this is the case...)

This results in the csv.reader returning the entire line as one value - so the output to the console is something like

```
line[1] = ['val1,val2,val3']
```

as would be expected.

- How can I correctly read this CSV file?

Comment: Are there quotes anywhere else?

Comment: @TimPietzcker no, I do not believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the file in a generator function to strip quotes:

```
def strip_quotes(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        yield line.rstrip('\n').strip('"') + '\n'
```

then use that function like:

```
fileReads = csv.reader(strip_quotes(csvfile), delimiter=',')
```

The `csv.reader()` class happily takes *any* iterable object, not just files.

The `strip_quotes()` function can be adjusted to fit your specific file contents. If there are quotes *around* columns as well, you could remove just *one* quote from the start and end of the line, for example.

Comment: Let's just hope that there never is a line that starts or ends with an actual quoted field...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: That can be accounted for. The point is more that you can use a generator function to pre-process lines.

Comment: Awesome, this works great - csv.reader must be pretty versatile? If I need to do more processing I can simply remove the first/last character of each line, etc..

Comment: @enderland: **Python** is pretty versatile. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's one of the reasons I keep spending effort to learn it... :)